# The correct usage of “branch off”

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have the following sentence in my textbook:

> The road to our house leaves the main road just after the service station.

(English Phrasal Verbs in Use, Advanced, Exercise 2.3)

It is asked to rewrite the sentence using the verb *branch* in an appropriate form. The textbook provides the following answer in the key:

> The road to our house *branches off* (the main road) just after the service station.

Is it correct to say “branch off the main road”? According to Cambridge Dictionary ([branch off, Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/branch-off)), the correct usage is:

> We drove down a narrow track that branched off **from** the main road.

That is, “from” is necessary, which makes perfect sense to me: the verb “branch off” is intransitive.

Comment: [Ngrams suggests that the version with *from* used to be the standard, but the *from*-less version has become more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=branch+off+the%2Cbranch+off+from+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: I'm not sure it's useful to say ***to branch off*** is an "intransitive verb" if that's what makes you think ***“from” is necessary*** in your final example (it isn't, so you've somehow reached the wrong conclusion). Would you say that because ***to jump off*** is "intransitive" in the same way (i.e. - ***He jumped off*** is fine), it's *necessary* to include ***from*** in, say, *He jumped off [from] the diving board*. If so, you'd be wrong there too - including the (second) preposition is a ***stylistic choice***.

Comment: @stangdon: Who knows how many instances in your NGram are for ***sawing** a branch off [from] the tree*?

Comment: ... [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+branch+off+the%2Cwhich+branch+off+from+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the same chart, but looking for ***which** branch off [from] the* (which should mean *every* match is gfor the sought context).

Comment: **typical usage is indeed**: **to branch off from [something else]**. So, you've written it **correctly**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A fair point.  We could also look at [branching off (from) the](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=branching+off+the%2Cbranching+off+from+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), which shouldn't have any confusion regarding tree branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a relevant usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which%20branch%20off%20the%2Cwhich%20branch%20from%20the%2Cwhich%20branch%20off%20from%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...which to me suggests that nothing much has changed regarding the choice of preposition after ***to branch*** over the last couple of centuries.

You can use ***off*** or ***from***, OR both. They all mean the same, and none are much more or much less common than any others, so it's entirely a stylistic choice which to use. Singling out ***to branch off*** as an "intransitive" verb doesn't seem particularly useful to me<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> See the results from [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22where+it+branches+the%22) for sentences *ending* with ***...where it branches*** (a perfectly valid use of intransitive ***to branch*** that *isn't* associated with any particular preposition).